# AWS Codeartifact not pointing to private repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codeartifact

Following the AWS instructions, I can authenticate codeartifact on Linux via

aws codeartifact login --tool twine --repository pypi-mystore --domain mydomain --dom
ain-owner xxxxxxxxxxx

But when trying to pip install some packages I get the following error:
404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/mypackage/

It looks like its pointing to pypi instead of my private repo

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

After successful execution of the login command, it should write to the following config file with details. Please confirm if this happens indeed:

```
~/.config/pip/pip.conf
```

Example:

```
» cat ~/.config/pip/pip.conf
[global]
index-url = https://<TOKEN>@my-domain-123456789012.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pypi/pypi-store/simple/
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `pip` rather than `twine` as the tool.

```
aws codeartifact login --tool pip --repository pypi-mystore --domain mydomain --dom ain-owner xxxxxxxxxxx
```